# Monitor daily, weekly and monthly bandwidth usage totals in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, performance, performance-counters

I need to be able to monitor and report on total bandwidth usage (in and out) on a windows 2008 server. This is so that i can cost the usage fees i am likely to incurr when moving to another datacenter provider.

I have tried Perfmon and data collectors, but cannot seem to get it to aggregate totals for me.

Does anyone know of a good way to do this ? Ideally i would be able to report on KB In, KB out of each network interface by day, week etc.

Many thanks

WU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) should do the trick.

Comment: Wow, thats great. Does exactly what i need, and about 100 other things more!. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: PRTG is awesome monitoring software. Highly recommend.